# Android XML based UI in Java

Tags: java, android, xml, user-interface

I would just like to have an Android XML UI file in Java. I have the XML file and I believe I need a parser that would actually generate the Java UI class file. Any ideas how to go about approaching this ?

EDIT: Well, let me explain this a little better. I am trying to track Google finance data for which I use gdata client library. However its authentication does not work in the Android environment, and so I am switching to Java SE. However, is there any library or something by which I can have the Android UI, without having to write my own parser. Need not necessarily be XML based.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write your own parser and instantiate the Swing classes that are synonymous with the controls described in the XML.